# What Cursed Child elements were foreshadowed by Rowling in previous writings?

Tags: harry-potter, jk-rowling, the-cursed-child, foreshadowing

We know that Jack Thorne wrote a play called *Harry Potter and the Cursed Child* with JKR's approval, and that Rowling claims to have given the creative team access to all the material she had prepared on the characters.

> **What changed your mind?**
>   **J.K. Rowling:** Meeting Sonya Friedman, Jack Thorne and John Tiffany changed my mind.
>   I knew there was other material there, I gave it all to them and they've turned out the play
>   <sub>([Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SNd54f0eGxk))</sub>

With this in mind, are there any specific elements first revealed in the Cursed Child which show signs of having been foreshadowed by Rowling in her own writings?

Comment: Off the top of my head, the destruction of the time turners, Harry's son being scared to not be in Gryffindor, naming seers, Malfoy not turning out to be *that evil* after all...

Comment: @ibid - Are you asking about foreshadowing in the Potter books? I took the quote to mean she gave them special privileged information - which we probably haven't had access to.

Comment: @Valorum - The destruction of Time-turners was explicitly stated by Rowling both in the books and in Pottermore, not just foreshadowed. Also, Rowling has said (on Pottermore) that Malfoy actually is *that evil*.

Comment: @ibid - You rascal.

Comment: @ThruGog - [This](http://jkrowling.com/wp-content/themes/jkrowling/assets/images/paper-notes-and-bracelet.png) may have been part of that.

Answer (score 9):

The main source of these is in Rowling's own next generation writings about the characters (i.e. The *Deathly Hallows* epilogue and [*The 2014 Quidditch World Cup articles.*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gixH.jpg))

Despite the parts which contradict Cursed Child (Albus is really an avid Quidditch fan), there are some things here which can be seen hinted to, even though they weren't actually revealed until the Cursed Child.

- **Albus will get sorted into Slytherin in contrast to the rest of his family**

  > All are wearing the red of Bulgaria except middle child Albus, who is sporting Brazilian green.
  >   <sub>([Pottermore - Quidditch World Cup Final](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmgVb.jpg))</sub>

  This was also somewhat implied in the Deathly Hallows epilouge.
- **Rose's last name is "Granger-Weasley"**

  This can be seen from the way that Hermione is constantly refereed to as 'Granger', while Ginny is referred to as 'Potter'.

  > Now married, Ronald Weasley and Hermione Granger were with Potter almost every step of the way.
  >   <sub>([Pottermore - Dumbledore's Army Reunites at the Quidditch World Cup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlB6H.png))</sub>
  >
  > Up in VIP Box Two, Ronald Weasley appears to have become catatonic. Did I just see wife Hermione Granger administer a sharp elbow to the ribs?
  >   <sub>([Pottermore - Quidditch World Cup Final](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmgVb.jpg))</sub>
  >
  > My colleague, Ginny Potter, who is sitting close enough to read everything my Quick-Quotes Quill is scribbling, informs me that Albus is a great fan of Brazilian Chaser Gonçalo Flores.
  >   <sub>([Pottermore - Quidditch World Cup Final](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmgVb.jpg))</sub>

  Note that Rowling would later used the "Granger-Weasley" last name in a (deleted) [tweet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M08LD.png).
- **Hermione will get promoted to Minister for Magic**

  > After a meteoric rise to Deputy Head of the Department of Magical Law Enforcement, she is now tipped to go even higher within the Ministry, and is also mother to son, Hugo, and daughter, Rose.
  >   <sub>([Pottermore - Dumbledore's Army Reunites at the Quidditch World Cup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlB6H.png))</sub>
  >
  > Hermione Granger is not wearing anything to indicate which team she is supporting. Does she secretly hope to see Krum take the trophy at last? Or is this the kind of diplomatic neutrality one might expect of a ruthless careerist whose long-term ambition is undoubtedly to be Minister for Magic?
  >   <sub>([Pottermore - Quidditch World Cup Final](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmgVb.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Althouth this is very much a matter of interpretation, I agree that the DH epilogue in itself foreshadows Albus's Sorting.

Comment: One could easily ask the question of almost any series of books, "How many plot points were deliberately placed in the early books, as opposed to the author poring through said books for a snippet of a comment they could use as a hook for a later event?" In most cases, a lot of those later events were not even a glimmer in the author's eye when they were writing book one. The same may well be so here.

Comment: @VBartilucci - This is different than most cases, as A) It wasn't intended as another instalment in a series, and B) It was written by a different author.

Comment: Rowling is listed as a co-author - I assume at the very least she made available notes or ideas she'd had for the characters, and likely had some sort of right of refusal to any of their ideas (which I suspect some wish she'd have used more liberally...). So if there were any deliberate ideas she had in the trunk, she might have shared them. All conjecture, obviously.

Comment: @VBartilucci - Technically she's listed as a co-collaborator, but anyways that was the propose of this question.

Comment: I'd never read those articles before. The [Quidditch World Cup Final](https://i.imgur.com/cwdXQ9g.png) article was brilliant!

Comment: @DougR. - Yeah, the 2014 QWC articles are probably the closest thing we'll ever get to an eighth Harry Potter book.